# How can I write test case scenarios in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I am trying to find an equivalent of Python Testcase scenarios (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testscenarios/) where one can list down the scenarios and then the test iterates over all the scenarios.